# Changing the value of an element that is inside of a nested list, given the index of that element

Tags: python, nested-lists

For example:

- I have a list

  `lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5`]
- I have the list of index of let's say the element 13 as `index=[2,3,1]` (i.e

  (`lst[2][3][1]==13`))
- How can I change the value to let's say 14 from 13 with that kind of
  input without importing any modules?

So updated list will be `[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14] ], [46, 83], 5]`

However, the solution should be something flexible because the index list changes for every element on that list. For some items, its length is 3 (like the element 13), but for some elements the length is something like 1(like the element 2, its index is `index = [1]`).

Comment: Are you asking how to make `lst[2][3][2] = val` with the indices coming from a list of `[2, 3, 2]`?

Comment: Exactly. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Set a variable to be your `lst`... Then loop over every index except the last and set that variable to be variable[index], then assign variable[last_index] to your value... (heck - you could even use `reduce` (which isn't an import in Py 2.x) if you really wanted, but  that's not quite as readable if you're not use to it)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to loop over the list of indices until you get to the last one. To make that process simpler, we can slice the last index from the rest.

```
lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5]
indices = [2, 3, 1]
newval = 14

*head, last = indices
temp = lst
for i in head:
    temp = temp[i]
temp[last] = newval
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
```

If you're running some old version of Python you may need to change that slice assignment to this less efficient version:

```
head, last = indices[:-1], indices[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Fun one (after I missed the "no imports", but see bottom part of the answer):

```
key, reduce(getitem, index, lst)[key] = index.pop(), value
```

Demo:

```
>>> if 1:
    from operator import getitem
    from functools import reduce

    lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5]
    index = [2,3,1]
    value = 14
    key, reduce(getitem, index, lst)[key] = index.pop(), value
    print(lst)

[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
```

No-imports version (only Python 2):

```
key, reduce(list.__getitem__, index, lst)[key] = index.pop(), value
```

Can't think of a oneliner for Python 3 other than a silly ugly stateful list comprehension... oh well, maybe if the OP is one of those people who say "no imports" when they really mean "no third party stuff", or maybe it's useful for others who have the same question except for this detail.

Comment: *without importing any modules?*

Answer (score 1):

Write a function.

```
>>> def list_setter(lst, idxs, val):
...     for i in idxs[:-1]:
...         lst = lst[i]
...     lst[idxs[-1]] = val
>>>
>>> lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5]
>>> list_setter(lst, [2,3,1], 14)
>>> lst
[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
>>> list_setter(lst, [0], 5)
>>> lst
[5, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
```

Add error checking as needed for indexing lists that are not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to traverse through nested lists, recursion is always a possibility:

```
lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13]], [46, 83], 5]
index=[2,3,1]
replace = 14

def rec_replace(lst, index, replace):
    if len(index) == 1:
        lst[index[0]] = replace
        return

    return rec_replace(lst[index[0]], index[1:], replace)

rec_replace(lst, index, replace)

print(lst)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is good but it works,

```
lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5]
indices = [2, 3, 1]
newval = 14
indices_str = "".join(["[" + str(i) + "]" for i in indices])
exec_stat = "{}{}={}".format('lst',indices_str, new_val)
exec(exec_stat)
```

Comment: Well, it's not great because `exec` is rather slow. Also, `exec` is generally avoided because it can be a security risk, although I guess that _shouldn't_ be an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this shorter recursion:

```
lst = [1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 13] ], [46, 83], 5]
index=[2,3,1]
val = 14
def mutate(lst, current):
   return [(lambda x:val if not all(c == d for c, d in zip(current+[i+1], index)) and len(current+[i]) == len(index) else x)(a) if isinstance(a, int) else mutate(a, current+[i]) for i, a in enumerate(lst)]
print(mutate(lst, []))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, [4, 6, 7, [11, 14]], [46, 83], 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all: the index of 13 is `[2, 3, 1]`, then you can just do this:

```
lst[2][3][1]=14
```